# Network Bound Disk Encryption (tang/clevis) Setup

Tags: systemd, security, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I am trying to have **NBDE** on **Ubunutu LTS 22.04.1** . basically i want my compute-1 node to auto decrypt on boot when it's able to ping controller (tang server) node. the problem is i encrypted every thing (lvm-luks2) except /boot partition

```
//Compute-1 node
lsblk
sda                           8:0    0   100G  0 disk
├─sda1                        8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                        8:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                        8:3    0    98G  0 part
  └─dm_crypt-0              253:0    0    98G  0 crypt
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0    90G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:2    0     8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]


apt install clevis clevis-luks clevis-initramfs

clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda3 tang '{"url":"<compute-node>:7500"}' (successful)
clevis luks list -d /dev/sda3 (returns tang server url)
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3 (token successfully added under clevis keyslot section)
```

now when i reboot it fails. it print some errors about my network interfaces i am pretty sure it's because i don't have networking at that level before decryption. [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption_security-hardening) said i should use `rd.neednet=1` to solve this issue. where should i put this? is it even possible to use in ubuntu ?

when i run `update-initramfs -u -k 'all'` i get error below

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--0)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

**Am I using a correct approach?**

Comment: You can enable network at boot with kernel parameters (even if they are actually interpreted by userland rather than kernel). Look for  procedures for dropbear-initramfs